# what is the difference between regex anchors \< and \>?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.9.3

I just introduced myself to `Regex` anchors `\<` and `\>` . But no code I found to see how they are used actually in a code. So in that context can you help me to understand with the help of a code how differently they meet the purposes?

I found these from [Cheat Sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/).

Thanks

Comment: Where did you see those anchors. Posting the link to the relevant resource would be beneficial.

Comment: If they are escaped, they are are just characters.

Comment: I have provided the link in my description! you can see that now!

Comment: The cheat sheet you are using is a general purpose reference. Not all expressions will work in all regex engines. I'm guessing that the expressions in that sheet are based on Perl.

Comment: For the sake of future readers, it is best not to update your question with the answer. You can accept an answer and that is enough. Otherwise, it can be difficult to tell what is being asked. You may also answer your own question if several answers must by synthesized to show what actually worked for you.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I did what you adviced! I love to respect my seniors alays! Thanks to guide me :)

Comment: That cheat sheet is a melange of features and syntax elements pulled apparently at random from many different flavors.  Notice how it also says `<` and `>` are metacharacters that have to be escaped with backslashes if you want to match them literally.  Just trash that thing and use Ruby's own docs or the [Oniguruma manpage](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\<` means the starting character for an expression and `\>` the character end. You can test the reqexp in ruby online at [rubular.com](http://rubular.com).

For example, this should give you true:

```
"<Hello>" =~ /\<Hello\>/
```

Comment: Are you confusing slashes and backslashes?

Comment: You listed `\>` twice. I think you meant `\<` in the first reference.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 why `Hello` within `<>` in the `LHS`?

Comment: @RubyTheBang - Because in Ruby, `\<` matches a '<' character, not the beginning of a word (like it might in other regex implementations). esimov was trying to create an input that would be matched by your pattern.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 thanks for remark, i misspelled the expression! Corrected

Answer (score 3):

They mean "start of word" (`\<`) and "end of word" (`\>`) where a "word" is an alphanumeric string. However, I don't think that Ruby supports them. They seem to be specific to a small subset of regex engines, especially POSIX EREs.

Most regex engines (including Ruby) only have word boundaries (`\b`), and they match at the start *or* end of a word, and they are sufficient for most use cases.

For example,  `/bar\b/` will match `"bar"` or (part of) `"rebar"` but not `"barf"`.

Comment: Can I have a tiny code to visualize those `anchors` please from your end!